# Wordpress Permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I'm using Wordpress Sydney theme on a very recently built website. If I change my permalinks to the post option, my webpage links break. Is there an easy way to fix this for someone who isn't a tech guru. Any (detailed) help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could depend on your host server - I used to host my sites on a Zeus server and had this same problem. You're probably not on a Zeus server, it's more common to be on Apache. You can check with phpinfo.

Create a file and call it phpinfo.php - include only this:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Upload it to your server and navigate to it in your browser (www.example.com/phpinfo.php) - look for Server API, if it's Apache then we'll need to look at your .htaccess rewrite rules.

If it's Zeus then, to my knowledge, you can't use pretty permalinks.